# Angular2 StockChart throws run time error - 'chart' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-components

I defined a component file with the name of 'GaugeComponent'. 
it has bellow import statement

```
import { StockChart } from 'angular-highcharts';
```

and i defined a function to bind data to stock chart as bellow.

```
public populateSpeedHystoryGraph(): void {

    this.stock = new StockChart({
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Speed of your car km/h'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                },

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            // tooltip: {
            //   valueDecimals: 2
            // },
            name: 'Speed',
            data: this.myData2

        }]
    });
}
```

my app.module.ts file has bellow import statment

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './@theme/theme.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';


import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import stock from 'highcharts/modules/stock.src';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src';

export function highchartsModules() {
  // apply Highcharts Modules to this array
  return [stock, more];
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),


    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // for database


    ChartModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: [APP_BASE_HREF, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES], useValue: '/'  , useFactory: highchartsModules},
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

but at the run time I am getting bellow error message:

core.js:1601 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'chart' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    ][chart]="stock">
  "): ng:///ChartsModule/HighchartGaugeComponent.html@1:9

any clue? am i missing any import statement here ?

Comment: the error is in `HighchartGaugeComponent.html`. Add this code to your question

Comment: The error means that it can't bind to the property `chart` of a `div`. It should recognize `chart` as a directive, and not a property if `angular-highcharts` is imported correctly.

Comment: @TimMartens - I have removed HighchartGaugeComponent.html and added
@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-highcharts-speed',    
    template: `
    <div [chart]="stockChart"></div>
  `

}) but still the error is there